# Convert BitMatrix output from QRCodeWriter to byte array?

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

I have an API which the frontend (PHP) calls to generate a QR code. The QR code is sent back as a byte array (`byte[]`). Currently we're using a paid library which can render the qr code to an `OutputStream`, like a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. But this library doesn't support some UTF-8 characters which is causing a problem for us. Going through the QR code generation process for ZXing we've noticed that the character set can be specified in a hashtable before encoding containing the QR code.

We would like to change the existing functionality as little as possible. Hence was wondering if it was possible to convert the BitMatrix output from the `QRCodeWriter.encode` method into a byte array?

Comment: All depends on what format your byatearray whould be?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto It should be in base64 format

Comment: Base64 is an encoding. I asked about format, like is it an image, like GIF, or some arbitrary/proprietary format?

Comment: Sorry about that, it should a JPG image.

Comment: Than you should use `MatrixToImageWriter` mentioned by **Boschi**.

Comment: Just tried it out now. It worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some sample code of reading and converting a BitMatrix by looking at the class `com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter` ([file on github](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/javase/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/j2se/MatrixToImageWriter.java))

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick implementation:

```kotlin
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter

val bitMatrix = qrCodeGenerator.encode("text", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300)
val os = OutputStream()
MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "PNG", os)
// do whatever with `os`
```

Don't forget to update `build.gradle`

```
// ...
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:javase:3.4.1'
}
// ...
```